# Converting Pandas header to string type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a dataframe which I read from a CSV as:

`df = pd.read_csv(csv_path, header = None)`

By default, Pandas assigns the header (`df.columns`) to be `[0, 1, 2, ...]` of type `int64`
What's the best way to to convert this to type `str`, such that `df.columns` results in `['0', '1', '2',...]` (i.e type `str`)?
Currently, the best way I can think of doing this is `df.columns = list(map(str, df.columns))`
Unfortunately, `df.astype(str)` only affects the values and not the column names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `astype(str)` with column names like this:

```
df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)
```

Example:

```
In [2472]: l = [1,2]
In [2473]: l1 = [2,3]

In [2475]: df = pd.DataFrame([l, l1])

In [2476]: df
Out[2476]: 
   0  1
0  1  2
1  2  3

In [2480]: df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)

In [2482]: df.columns
Out[2482]: Index(['0', '1'], dtype='object')
```