# Dataframe colum header as Object returning "KeyError" using Pandas

Tags: pandas, types, keyerror

I'm aggregating some data before analysis. I've got a dataframe which looks like that :

```
    ID                  Year    Electricity consumption (kWh)
0   102520_1000010472   NaN     NaN
1   102521_1000010472   2011    29.0
2   102521_1000010472   2012    29.0
3   102521_1000010472   2013    29.0
4   102521_1000010472   2014    109644556.0
...     ...                     ...     ...
```

The types are as follows :

```
ID                                object
Year                              object
Electricity consumption (kWh)    float64
dtype: object
```

I then pivot the table to get the data in line. Up to there, no problem.

`df2 = df.pivot_table(index='ID', columns='Year', values='Electricity consumption (kWh)').round(0) df2 = df2.reset_index()`

```
Year    ID                  2011    2012    2013    ...
0       102521_1000010472   29.0    29.0    29.0    ...
...
```

Then I need to call a specific colum. For exemple :

`df2['2012']`

Python gives me here a KeyError.

I identify this as being a problem with my datatype. I if call the following :
`df2[2012]`
It does return the expected Series :

```
0       29.0
1        NaN
2       15.0
3        NaN
4       15.0
```

But working with this puts me in other difficulties for plotting for instance. I'd like to have the headers being read as strings and not integers using `df['2012']`. I tried the following.

**1.renaming the headers :**

```
dict = {2010: '2010',
        2011: '2011',
        ...: '...'}
 
df.rename(columns=dict,
          inplace=True)
```

But of course it doesn't work, as the dict expects strings as a key

**2.changing the header type:**

I followed the following thread : [Converting Pandas header to string type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65463326/converting-pandas-header-to-string-type)
But applying this does raises another error which I don't really understand here.

```
TypeError: Cannot cast Index to dtype <U0
```

Any help or suggestion would be gladly appreciated ! And sorry if my explanations aren't cristal clear, my first time posting here and still a big newbie to coding.

I'm using Python 3.8.2 and Pandas 1.4.2

Comment: I can't reproduce it.  The `df2` after you did the pivot should give you the correct headers. Is there maybe a value in df["year"] which is a non-ascii value? (https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/45326)

Comment: No, just NaN or numbers. But that was a nice idea. Thanks for looking into it. @ScottC 's suggestion made it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To change the header type, you can call:**

```
df2.columns = df2.columns.astype(str)
```

#### For example,

If I set up a dataframe to match yours as best I can:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'ID': ['102520_1000010472', '102521_1000010472', '102521_1000010472', '102521_1000010472', '102521_1000010472'],
                    'Year': [np.nan, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014],
                    'Electricity consumption (kWh)': [np.nan, 29.0, 29.0, 29.0, 109644556.0]}, dtype='object')

df['Electricity consumption (kWh)'] = df['Electricity consumption (kWh)'].astype('float')
print(df.dtypes)
```

#### Output:

```
ID                                object
Year                              object
Electricity consumption (kWh)    float64
dtype: object
```

Then do the pivot operation as you did:

```
df2 = df.pivot_table(index='ID', columns='Year', values='Electricity consumption (kWh)').round(0) 
df2 = df2.reset_index()
print(df2)
```

#### Output:

```
Year                 ID  2011  2012  2013         2014
0     102521_1000010472  29.0  29.0  29.0  109644556.0
```

If I check the types of the columns:

```
for i in df2.columns:
    print(type(i))
```

#### Output:

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
```

Then do the conversion as suggested:

```
df2.columns = df2.columns.astype(str)
for i in df2.columns:
    print(type(i))
```

#### Output:

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
```

Now you can call the dataframe as you wanted:

```
print(df2['2012'])
```

#### Output:

```
0    29.0
Name: 2012, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I also had thought about doing the type change before pivoting but got also some error. I followed your guidelines and it worked just fine.